# Simple_Form f.button :button throws a "not a symbol" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Rails: 4.0.0

Ruby: 2.0.0

According to

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/plataformatec-simpleform/dxvrRaizMYk

and

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/814

But when I try that I get an error:

> {:class=>"button"} is not a symbol

For line

```
= f.button :button
```

In my gemfile I have

```
gem 'simple_form'
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: try `= f.button "submit"`. This should generate a button with submit as the text.

Comment: I have following in my view `<%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary span3' %>` and I think you need to pass symbol expected by Simple Form.

Comment: According to the links above though, they're saying it should work. And I don't like f.button :submit because it renders an input element (type = submit) instead of a button element/tag. If you look at the style it's slightly different too (css wise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Rails 4 support in `SimpleForm` will be introduced in version 3.0.0 which is not released yet you have to use it from master branch for now. This should fix your issue:

`ruby
gem 'simple_form', github: 'plataformatec/simple_form'`